# sqlite3 memory issues with CREATE INDEX on a large table

Tags: sqlite

I have a really big table, with billions of rows.  When I try to make an index on it, sqlite3 crashes with a "bus error".  I'm running sqlite 3.8.4.1 on linux with 10G of memory, and page size = 1096, and I tried environment variables

```
export TMPDIR=/home/tmp
export SQLITE_TMPDIR=/home/tmp
```

and setting

```
PRAGMA cache_size=2000;
```

before doing my create index command.  Anyone have any ideas? Or is sqlite with billions of rows just doomed?

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say if you have billions of rows in sqlite, you shouldn't be using sqlite.

Comment: Try updating to a version that is not over three years out of date.

Comment: Wow, thank you @CL.  ...now I feel dumb.  Should I delete this Q?

Comment: Write an answer about how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to the help of @CL.'s comment, by updating to sqlite3 3.21

Regarding @dzm's comment, my database does have tables with a few billion rows but so far (with the newer sqlite) it seems that it works.  I'm planning on using it for read-only analysis purposes, but I'm going to also try copying it to mysql because of all the negative press on sqlite for large data.